# Why dlclose() must not be called from a signal handler?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries, signals

I have written a user-space application in `C` which interacts with a low-level Linux kernel driver using a plugin library `plugin.so`. I open the DLL using `dlopen()`. I have a signal handler which calls `dlclose()` when `SIGINT` is received. After code review, I got feedback comments that *`dlclose()` must not be called from a signal handler*. If yes, why is it so?

Comment: Think about what may happen if there's another signal while in `dlclose`, especially if it happens to be a second `SIGINT` (user presses CTRL-C twice) and you try to call `dlclose` _again_. See e.g. [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04) for more information about signals, and a list of functions deemed safe to call in a signal handler.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Shouldn't `dlclose` take care of all these stuff, like being re-entrant so that there is no dependency on how the user uses the library. What if I open/close a normal file in signal handler.

Comment: Btw. what type of code review is it where you can not ask the reviewer for the reasons behind their comments?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I got the code review comments through email. So, just wanted to clarify before replying to them.

Comment: @Manav: Implementing `dlclose()` in a reentrant way resides between really hard and impossible to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, because `dlclose()` is not listed in the POSIX list of functions safe to be called in a signal handler.

The reason for this is mainly that a lot of those functions not listed there may do things like allocating memory etc. that need to do things that could have a race condition with the signal handler. One example would be to hold a lock, so when the signal arrives in a thread that currently holds some lock belonging to malloc/dlclose or whatever, and you call that function, then the lock is already locked, but will never be unlocked since the thread is currently in the signal handler, and not executing "normally".

Comment: How is `close(fd)` of a normal file different from closing a library using `dlclose()`

Comment: @Manav: `close(fd)` very likely only translates to a syscall into the kernel, while `dlclose` will usually have to `munmap()` the shared object, and probably to destroy some bookkeeping structures as well.

Comment: The library has exposed a `dll_destroy` API also. Would it be safer to call it directly from signal handler?

Comment: @Manav: I have no idea what that API does, read its documentation for if it is possible to call it from within a signal handler, but I personally doubt it, since it is very likely that this API itself calls functions that are not safe to be called within a signal handler context (like e.g. `dlclose()`)